# Which Statistical Test can I use for my experiment?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

So I handed out a survey and asked 100 people if they frequently went out before a community quarantine started (yes/no). I also asked the same 100 people if they frequently went outside after the community quarantine was lifted (yes/no).

What type of Statistical Test can I use to analyze the data I have received? I think that I should do a test on the difference in population proportions but I am not sure if there are better tests for this data. Is this an appropriate test to use? And if this is the correct test to use, is an appropriate null hypothesis p1 (number of people who went out before quarantine) = p2 (number of people who went out after quarantine)? Is a significance level of a = 0.05 good for this experiment as well?

Comment: What high-level question are you trying to answer? You need a hypothesis (i.e. a statement you're interested in that the data may or may not support) in order to do a statistical test; the test tells you whether the data supports your hypothesis.